# Trying to run MVC 3 website plus EntityFramework with Mono gives MissingMethodException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, xamarin-studio

I built an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2012. My application builds and runs without any issues in Visual Studio. I want to edit and run that web application using Xamarin Studio 4.0 with Mono 3.0.4 on OS X 10.8.2. Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Opened my .sln in Xamarin Studio.
2. Deleted references to System.Data.Entity and System.Web.Entity.
3. Copied System.Web.Helpers (version 1.0.0.0), System.Web.Mvc (version 3.0.0.0), and System.Web.WebPages (version 1.0.0.0) .dlls to bin folder.
4. Removed old references to System.Web.Helpers, System.Web.Mvc, and System.Web.Webpages.
5. Replaced "using System.Data.*" with "using System.Data.Entity.Core.*" in my *.Designer.cs files.
6. Deleted reference to EntityFramework (version 4.x).
7. Deleted EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.xml from my bin folder.
8. Added a reference to /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/mono/4.5/EntityFramework.dll (version 6.0.0.0).
9. Click run.

After I click run, I get the following exception:

```
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Web.Configuration.HostingEnvironmentSection ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty..ctor'.
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x000b9] in /Users/duncan/git/mono/bockbuild/profiles/mono-mac-release/build-root/mono-3.0.4/_build/mono-3.0.4.git/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:524 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x002fb] in /Users/duncan/git/mono/bockbuild/profiles/mono-mac-release/build-root/mono-3.0.4/_build/mono-3.0.4.git/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Hosting/ApplicationHost.cs:244 
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-master/3108f76b/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-mac-release/build-root/xsp-2.11/_build/mono-xsp-d3e2f80/src/Mono.WebServer/VPathToHost.cs:150 
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) [0x00775] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-master/3108f76b/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-mac-release/build-root/xsp-2.11/_build/mono-xsp-d3e2f80/src/Mono.WebServer.XSP/main.cs:486 
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/mono-mac-ui-refresh-master/3108f76b/source/bockbuild/profiles/mono-mac-release/build-root/xsp-2.11/_build/mono-xsp-d3e2f80/src/Mono.WebServer.XSP/main.cs:264
```

I've Googled the exception, but I haven't found a solution. Am I missing a reference? Is there a working example project anywhere that uses MVC 3 or 4 and Entity Framework 4 or 6 that runs under Mono?

Comment: Please file bug in xamarin bugzilla (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com)